# Do not understand this example of RegExp, .ignoreCase & .test() and how it works

Tags: javascript

I used this code example for a class problem but I Googled the answer and though people said their is nothing wrong with that, i have a major issue because I used code I didn't understand fully.
I had to use both variables regex1 and regex2 to make it work but didn't understand why, also didn't understand why the code wouldn't work without the i in regex2.  All I wanted to do was use the .ignoreCase and .test() but it only works in this manner.  I don't recall what I did exacly in class test but I want to understand this, been reading Mozilla for a couple hours and still lost on how this works.

```js
//This roughly what I used if I recall everything correctly.
var regex1 = new RegExp('virg');
var regex2 = new RegExp('virgil','i');
regex2.ignoreCase;
console.log(regex2.test('Virgilio'));


//This was the example I used but don't understand
var regex1 = new RegExp('foo');
var regex2 = new RegExp('foo', 'i');

console.log(regex1.test('Football'));   // expected output: false
console.log(regex2.ignoreCase);         // expected output: true
console.log(regex2.test('Football'));   // expected output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` flag is used when you want to ignorecase while matching, which means if you use `i` flag regex engine will treat `uppercase` and `lowercase` letters as same.

```
 Example 'A' === 'a' // true  in case of `i` flag active
         'A' === 'a' // false in case of `i` flag not active
```

[**Regex.ignoreCase**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase) is used to test whether the `i` flag is activated or not, and it's a **Read only property**

Comment: Thank you so much that 'i' was driving me nuts trying to figure out why it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

The example is to explain how works the i flag parameter.

```
var regex1 = new RegExp('foo');        // case sensitive
var regex2 = new RegExp('foo', 'i');  // case insensitive

console.log(regex1.test('Football'));   // show false, because 'F' <> 'f'
console.log(regex2.ignoreCase);         // show true, because i flag was used in regex2. Otherwise false
console.log(regex2.test('Football'));   // show true, because 'Football' contains 'foo' and dont care lower and upper case
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize the 'i' was a flag, I thought it was just another string.